# Juju charm application is not getting removed

Tags: ubuntu, juju

I have a charm named my-rts on my machine which failed while starting. Now I am try to remove the application, unit and machine but it does not gets deleted somehow.

I tried to remove all 3 using commands:

```
$ juju remove-machine 3
$ juju remove-unit my-rts/0
$ juju remove-application my-rts
```

And then on `juju status`, I see them still there.

```
$ juju status
Model    Controller  Cloud/Region         Version
default  test        localhost/localhost  2.0.2

App     Version  Status  Scale  Charm   Store       Rev  OS      Notes
my-rts           error       1  my-rts  jujucharms    0  ubuntu  

Unit       Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports  Message
my-rts/0*  error     idle   3        10.206.116.199         hook failed: "start"

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id        Series  AZ
3        stopped  10.206.116.199  juju-f1075c-3  trusty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that i was missing a very common solution for such situation. That is to do it forcefully.

`juju remove-machine MachineID --force` helped.

More information can be found @ https://github.com/juju/juju/issues/5293

Comment: what is the MachineID though ?